# How can i get back the default in build Gpu driver After medding up my gpu drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

My gpu drivers are messed up they are still in a working condition but my games fps are not as good as they were before

Output of command  # sudo lshw -c video | grep product:

product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]

I was trying to install Proprietary drivers
I download [Linux x86_64](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-8000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-8670m-series-gpu)
that gived me a output of

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.20.6_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.20.6_64a:none:4.15.0-33-generic:)

then i Install PPA third-party drivers
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

this was working and i am using these drivers right now
but I dont want these drivers

Is there a way to remove these driver or not and use the default one

or can someone guide me get the best drivers for my gpu I am useing Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

U made a mistake in ppa driver installation
Execute these commands to install ppa drivers

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
2. sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
   Done